# Functions with different signatures, but the same body

Tags: java, overloading, constructor-overloading

Consider a class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ShortcutButton extends JButton {
    public ShortcutButton(String text, KeyStroke[] keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }
    public ShortcutButton(String text, KeyStroke keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }
    public ShortcutButton(String text, String[] keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }
    public ShortcutButton(String text, String keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }

    public void addShortcuts(KeyStroke[] keyStrokes) {
        for (KeyStroke keyStroke : keyStrokes) {
            addShortcut(keyStroke);
        }
    }
    public void addShortcuts(String[] keyStrokes) {
        for (String keyStroke : keyStrokes) {
            addShortcut(keyStroke);
        }
    }
    public void addShortcut(String keyStroke) {
        addShortcut(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(keyStroke));
    }
    public void addShortcut(KeyStroke keyStroke) {
       //some code here
    }
}
```

As you can see, `ShortcutButton()` coonstructors and `addShortcuts()` functions have defferent signatures, but the same body. Is there a pretty way to make this code shorter in order not to copy-paste the same code in four different functions?

Comment: Perhaps the most important thing you can do is delete code. Repeatedly having "helpful" overloads isn't helpful. (Also "prefer composition over inheritance" (or a static method over inheritance), but that seems like a lost cause in GUI programming.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can reduce them into two constructors if you reorder the arguments and use varargs:

```
public ShortcutButton(String text, ActionListener actionListener, KeyStroke... keyStrokes) {
    super(text);
    addActionListener(actionListener);
    addShortcuts(keyStrokes);
}
public ShortcutButton(String text, ActionListener actionListener, String... keyStrokes) {
    super(text);
    addActionListener(actionListener);
    addShortcuts(keyStrokes);
}
```

and if you have a method that converts a `String[]` to a `KeyStroke[]`, you can further shorten the code:

```
public ShortcutButton(String text, ActionListener actionListener, KeyStroke... keyStrokes) {
    super(text);
    addActionListener(actionListener);
    addShortcuts(keyStrokes);
}
public ShortcutButton(String text, ActionListener actionListener, String... keyStrokes) {
    this(text,actionListener,getShortCuts(keyStrokes));
}
```

Comment: Watch those empty arrays! I suggest checking if the length is `>=1`

Comment: @MarkJeronimus good point, though that could be the responsibility of `addShortcuts(keyStrokes)` (that method should check for empty array in the OP's original code too).

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other answers, you can also use a trick to at least pull `addActionListener(actionListener);` out of your specialized constructors by adding a private constructor. This is not an alternative for the varargs trick from the other answer. You can apply both tricks to get even smaller code.

```
public class ShortcutButton extends JButton {
    /** Construct a ShortcutButton without keystrokes. Any constructor calling this should add keystrokes themselves. */
    private ShortcutButton(String text, ActionListener actionListener) {
        super(text);
        addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

    public ShortcutButton(String text, KeyStroke[] keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        this(text, actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }

    public ShortcutButton(String text, KeyStroke keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        this(text, actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }

    public ShortcutButton(String text, String[] keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        this(text, actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }

    public ShortcutButton(String text, String keyStrokes, ActionListener actionListener) {
        this(text, actionListener);
        addShortcut(keyStrokes);
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create generic methods as shown below:

```
 public<T> void addShortcuts(T[] keyStrokes) {
     for (T keyStroke : keyStrokes) {
         addShortcut(keyStroke);
     }
 }
```

Comment: new ShortcutButton<Integer>(text, 123, actionListener) -> fail

Comment: @MarkJeronimus thanks for pointing that out. I mistook the constructor for method.The questioner can use the approach mentioned in the other answer. And the above approachcan be used for the addShortcut method.